# IIS site taking an extremely long time to load?

Tags: windows, php, mysql, iis

I have a local copy of my website running on IIS 8 (this is in the Windows 8 RP) with the latest version of PHP with FastCGI, and a complete MySQL install (I selected the lowest memory using option in the MySQL set up, if that matters). For some reason, I'm getting very long load times for my site.

some debugging info that might help:

- when using the method described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/5422809/602472 to time the execution of my page, from the first , the PHP compilation time for my homepg.php document is 7.1525573730469E-6 seconds, which I take to mean less than a second according to http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=7.1525573730469E-6
- the load time for that homepg.php document (according to IE's network tab, and chrome's networking tab) is about six seconds, and then another 20 seconds for an API page (that's also part of the same IIS website), but whose "initiator" is XMLHttpRequest (indicating that it was sent from a jQuery $.GET), and is actually a file about 7 kB smaller than homepg.php, but homepg.php's initiator is "refresh," so is it at all possible that that could be the problem?
- this occurs with or without the dynamic/static compression in IIS.
- it's not a problem with my network connection, since I've tried it on multiple wifi routers and ISPs
- it's also not a problem with like DNS or anything, since the slowdown occurs when I use 127.0.0.1 and all of the custom domains I've set in the hosts file.

My apologies if this is a bit vague, but since I have near-0 experience in this I wasn't exactly sure what would be most helpful in trouble shooting :\ If you need any more info, just ask :)

Thanks,

Matthew

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turned out to be a problem with the way I was connecting to MySQL - I needed to replace "localhost" with "127.0.0.1" as was recommended in many other threads (but I kind of dismissed it as not gonna work for me when I saw those solutions, so I should have tried that before posting here)

So, if you're server is taking forever when doing anything with MySQL, try changing "localhost" (or other hostnames) to "127.0.0.1" (or other IP addresses) :D